# Hey, How to collect sms Consent in laravel from klaviyo php-sdk in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, sdk

Hey guys does anyone knows the way around to add an SMS content in klaviyo from [this package in laravel.](https://github.com/klaviyo/php-klaviyo#or-just-add-a-property-to-someone)

Basically I've added this piece of code where I can add the profile and see that green check next to user's email but for SMS it don't appear there. After reading some similar issues faced by others, I found that we need a subscribe endpoint of API to add consent of SMS, But I still can't find a way to do it with this package. Any help and suggestions would be appreciated.

````
use Klaviyo\Klaviyo as Klaviyo;
use Klaviyo\Model\EventModel as KlaviyoEvent;
use Klaviyo\Model\ProfileModel as KlaviyoProfile;


class KlaviyoformsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $client = new Klaviyo('Your_private_key', 'public key');
        $event =
            new KlaviyoEvent(
                array(
                    'event' => 'Lead',
                    'customer_properties' => array(
                        '$email' => "someone@mailinator9.com",
                        '$consent' => ['sms', 'email'],
                        'sms_consent' => true,
                        'email_consent' => true,
                        '$first_name' => "Thomas9",
                        '$last_name' => "Jefferson",
                        '$phone_number' => "1234567890"
                    ),
                    'properties' => array()
                )
                );
        



        $client->publicAPI->track( $event, true );
        return view('klaviyoform::dashboard.index');
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You must have a capture form for the consent submission within Laravel that will then subscribe them with the appropriate consent data. You must explicitly ask for **both** email and sms consent.

```
$client = new Klaviyo('Your_private_key', 'public key');

$customer_properties =  [
    '$email' => "someone@mailinator9.com",
    '$first_name' => "Thomas9",
    '$last_name' => "Jefferson",
    'phone_number' => "1234567890"
];

$consents = [];

if (request()->get('sms_consent', false)) {
  $consents['sms_consent'] = true;
}

if (request()->get('email_consent', false)) {
  $consents['email_consent'] = true;
}

foreach ($consents as $type => $consented) {
  if ($consented) {
    $consents['$consent'] = array_merge(
        data_get($consents, '$consent', []), 
        [explode('_', $type)[0]] //e.g. sms, email
    );
  }
}

$client->lists->addSubscribersToList('ListId', array_merge($customer_properties, $consents));
```

This is relative psuedo code but the goal is clear: Determine if they allowed **both** sms and email consent. If so, we'll add their consent properties.

Once the consent data has been added to that list you can safely send them sms and/or email based on the customers choice.

Comment: Hey thank you for the explanation, I tried to make changes but then there's this issue `Cannot access offset of type string on a string` on the front. Is it because the array structure may be improper?