# I hit this error while integrating klaviyo with laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, string, api

I'm using [this package As SDK](https://github.com/klaviyo/php-klaviyo#or-just-add-a-property-to-someone). So basically what I'm trying to achieve is to add the users to a list but with the consent status or email and SMS, What I found from one answer from my own question is this code. So I tried it but then it hit another error.

```
TypeError
Cannot access offset of type string on string
```

Code from @Ohgodwhy's [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68943007/hey-how-to-collect-sms-consent-in-laravel-from-klaviyo-php-sdk-in-laravel)

```
public function chnages()
    {
        $client = new Klaviyo('Your_Private_apikey', 'Public_Api_key');
        $customer_properties =  [
            '$email' => "someone@mailinator9.com",
            '$first_name' => "Thomas9",
            '$last_name' => "Jefferson",
            'phone_number' => "1234567890"
        ];
        $consents = [];
        if (request()->get('sms_consent', false)) {
            $consents['sms_consent'] = true;
        }
        if (request()->get('email_consent', false)) {
            $consents['email_consent'] = true;
        }
        foreach ($consents as $type => $consented) {
            if ($consented) {
                $consents['$consent'] = array_merge(
                    data_get($consents, '$consent', []),
                    [explode('_', $type)[0]] //e.g. sms, email
                );
            }
        }

        $client->lists->addSubscribersToList('LIST_ID', array_merge($customer_properties, $consents));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$consents['$consent']` this is not going to work, array values can be either a variable OR a string but not a variable inside a string. Also, you don’t have $consent in your foreach, to check the $consents key value you need to do `$consents[$type]`
The same thing counts for `data_get($consents, '$consent', [])` which need to be `data_get($consents, $consented, [])`