# Not able to check consent status for sms in klaviyo laravel package

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, api

I've tried to integrate klaviyo with laravel with this piece of code But it only adds the consent for email(green checkbox next to the email in klaviyo), But it should also add consent for SMS the same way for email. What Am I doing wrong here? So far I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68943007/hey-how-to-collect-sms-consent-in-laravel-from-klaviyo-php-sdk-in-laravel/68943369#68943369) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68944985/i-hit-this-error-while-integrating-klaviyo-with-laravel) but hit a different error.

```
 public function chnages()
    {
        $client = new Klaviyo('Private_Api_key', 'Public_key');
        $profile = new KlaviyoProfile(
            array(
                '$email' => 'thomas1.jefferson@mailinator.com',
                '$first_name' => 'Thomas11',
                '$last_name' => 'Jefferson',
                '$consent' => ['sms','email'],
                '$sms_consent' => true,
                '$phone_number' => "1234567890",
                'Plan' => 'Premium'
            )
        );
        // dd($profile);
        $client->lists->addSubscribersToList('Klaviyo_list_id', array($profile));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys here is the proper code which I came up for laravel, Basically, you gotta send the request from form to this function and then follow up on this code and API documentation from [here](https://apidocs.klaviyo.com/reference/lists-segments#subscribe). ***Note: SMS consent can only be passed by from subscribing endpoint so there's already URL which I mentioned.*** Feel free to ask and suggest on this thread.

```
        public function forform(Request $request)
    {
        $ifsmscheckd = $request->input('sms_consent') ? true : false; //if input is there then its true
        if ($ifsmscheckd) {
            // if both checkd
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, [
                CURLOPT_URL => "https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v2/list/{LIST_ID}/subscribe?api_key=PRIVATE_KEY",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
                    'profiles' => [
                        [
                            'email' => $request->input('name'),
                            'phone_number' => $request->input('phone_number'),
                            'sms_consent' => $request->input('sms_consent') ? true : false,
                            '$consent' => ['sms', 'email']
                        ],
                    ],
                ]),
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                    "Accept: application/json",
                    "Content-Type: application/json"
                ],
            ]);

            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $err = curl_error($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            if ($err) {
                echo "cURL Error #:" . $err . "cmdskcmdsl";
            } else {
                echo $response;
            }
        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the correct solution so not to misinform!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69004266/1060364

Comment: Hi, Yes I've tried doing it but still it creates custom properties
like consent sms, email. NOT Those green checks as what we have right now like this https://ibb.co/9rLbwrs for consent in woocom wordpress.

Comment: And for consent we have to pass it with a $dollar sign as its klaviyo property but it has to do something with subscribe end point which I don't know at all. There's this documentation https://help.klaviyo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360054803711-Guide-to-Collecting-SMS-Consent-via-API but the code sample is in python and it's not to the point I guess, How do we do it in PHP from Form Request?

Comment: Ah -you're right.  Consent variables are also reserved. 

As for the difference between Add and Subscribe. AFAIK, in Klaviyo, the API has a "Add to List" and a "Subscribe to List" - which sound the same, but aren't.  Subscribe will abide by the List settings like single/double-optin etc, and I think is the one that adds the consent (for email at least).  Add to List, is adding it without the above requirements for situations where you're syncing contacts to Klaviyo to append custom properties later, but you don't want it to imply that they subscribed.

Comment: It looks like you wrote your own GET request to do this. Sorry I took you down the wrong path!

Comment: Yes sir haha after banging my head for hours and days I found this after reading very details of documents and people's issues, it's always worthy when we search for other issues for some sample codes haha.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following works using https://github.com/klaviyo/php-klaviyo.  This package is deprecated but it is what we are using at the moment.  Sorry can not update the package at this time.

```
public function subscribeMemberToSMSList($list, $phonenumber){
        $NUM_OF_ATTEMPTS = 5;
        $attempts = 0;            
        $profile = new KlaviyoProfile(array('$phone_number'=>$phonenumber, 'phone_number' => $phonenumber, 'sms_consent' => true));              
        $arrayOfProfiles = array($profile);
        
        do {
            try{                     
                $listresponse = $this->client->lists->subscribeMembersToList($list, $arrayOfProfiles);                    
                return 'Success';                    
            } catch (Exception $e)
            {                        
                    $attempts++;
                    $pos = strpos($e->getMessage(), 'Request was throttled.');                
                    if ($pos === false) {                                             
                        return $e->getMessage();
                    } else {
                        $int = (int) filter_var($e->getMessage(), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                        if($int < 10){
                            sleep($int);
                        } else {
                            sleep(5);
                        }
                        continue;
                    }                        
            }               
        } while($attempts < $NUM_OF_ATTEMPTS);
    }
```